# PHP MySQL, UNION TABLES

Tags: mysql, union

Got a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM job WHERE status!=2 AND status!=3
UNION SELECT * FROM emp WHERE status!=2 AND status!=3
ORDER BY (id/popularity) DESC LIMIT {$from},$vpc
```

It works perfectly, but now can't identify where from record is coming...
Is there any way to identify from which table, the record is coming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you could try this:

```
      SELECT *, 'job' as origin 
        FROM job 
       WHERE status!=2 
         AND status!=3
UNION SELECT *, 'emp' as origin
        FROM emp 
       WHERE status!=2 
         AND status!=3
    ORDER BY (id/popularity) DESC 
       LIMIT {$from},$vpc
```

This should add a field named origin to your results, containing a name of your choice to identify the table.